# Typeorm in nestjs - using save() to replace all children in a parent in onetomany relation does not delete old children

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have the following parent, child entities defined in my nestjs project:

***parent entity***

```
@Entity()
export class Parent{

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  parentId: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Children, (child) => child.parent, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true,
  })
  children: Children[];

}
```

And ***Child Entity***:

```
@Entity()
export class Children{

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  childId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  parent: Parent;
}
```

And I'm trying to replace the entire children in parent with the following logic:

```
const newChildren = [ new Children(), new Children()];
const parent = parentRepository.findOneBy({parentId:id});
parent.children = newChildren;
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

Problem here is that this action does not delete the old children in the childrenRepository. It just creates this new children in childrenRepository.

***What I wanted to achieve is, when I try to replace entire children of a parent in a onetomany relation, the old children should get deleted from the childrenRepository.***

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option called `orphanedRowAction` in typeorm that resolves this.

```
@ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children, {
 onDelete: 'CASCADE',
 onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
 orphanedRowAction: 'delete',
})
parent: Parent;  


    /**
 * When a parent is saved (with cascading but) without a child row that still exists in database, this will control what shall happen to them.
 * delete will remove these rows from database.
 * nullify will remove the relation key.
 * disable will keep the relation intact. Removal of related item is only possible through its own repo.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

This TypeORM code:

```js
  @ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  parent: Parent;
```

This means that:

1. `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` if you delete the parent, the children will all get deleted.
2. `onUpdate: 'CASCADE'` - couldn't find TypeORM docs on this, but since it's not deleting orphaned children for you, I'm guessing the delete you are expecting is an unwanted side effect from TypeORM perspective.

One solution could be being explicit about deleting the orphaned children, like this:

```js
import { In } from "typeorm"
...
const newChildren = [ new Children(), new Children()];
const parent = parentRepository.findOneBy({parentId:id});
const deleteChildrenResult = await childrenRepository.delete({
  id: In(parent.children.map((child) => child.childId)),
});
parent.children = newChildren;
parentRepository.save(parent);
```